# javascript object loops replace info

Tags: javascript, loops, object

In the "topSecret" function “spy” will be passed in as an object that represents a spy. Loop through all the properties on the spy object and change all values to the string “redacted”, then return the updated spy object.

Can anyone help me to find a starting point for this. I am completely lost. Thank you!!

```
var topSecret = function(spy){
    //insert code here
}
```

Comment: `for (var key in spy)` ... or `Object.keys(spy).forEach`

Comment: This sounds like homework. Why don't you try to solve it by yourself

Answer (score -1):

If I understand you correctly:

```
var topSecret = function(spy){
    var key;

    for (key in spy) {
        if (spy.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
            spy[key] = 'redacted';
        }
    }

    return spy;
}
```

But original "spy"-object will be changed too

Comment: `return the updated spy object` suggests that's the goal :p

Comment: I'd be careful using `for...in` without a `.hasOwnProperty` check

Comment: Thank you for you help everyone this is starting to make sense bit by bit now